# Angular async reactive form Validation

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms

I have been looking lots of tutorials to could implement async validators to a reactive form in angular but I always get an error.

What I need to do, is to check a value written in a field exists in an array of objects stored in a service.

The problem is that the validator works fine when I do the comparison to a fixed value, but when I try to use the service it says that the service is undefined.

**Code for the form:**

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.FormNuevaConf =this.fb.group({
  'codigo': [null,null],
  'valor': [null,null,this.valorUnicoValidator]
})}
```

**Code for the validator:**

```
valorUnicoValidator (control: AbstractControl, service:UnidadesService): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
return of(service.subscribe(control) === control.value).pipe(
  map(result => result ? { invalid: true } : null)
  );}
```

`subscribe(control)` is a function in the service that returns a value if the `control.value` is found in the array of objects returned from the db query.

I haven't found a clear explanation of how to build an async validator if you have one you can recommend me I will thank that.

Comment: I found your question in the process of trying to figure out my problem and found a much better answer here: https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Answer (score 0):

The service cannot be injected in the validator, **you have to inject it as private in the constructor of your component class** and then use it in the validator since you will have access to it.

Something like:

```
constructor(private service: UnidadesService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.FormNuevaConf =this.fb.group({
    'codigo': [null,null],
    'valor': [null,null,this.valorUnicoValidator]
  })
}

valorUnicoValidator (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return of(this.service.subscribe(control) === control.value).pipe(
      map(result => result ? { invalid: true } : null)
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a validator builder like this if your component has a copy of the service instance that you want.

myValidator.validator.ts:

```
export function MyValidator(service: MyService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
        if (service.getValue()) {
            return { Error: true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

in your component:

```
this.noteForm.addControl("MyFormContorl", new FormControl(null,
            [Validators.required, MyValidator(this.myService)]));
```

Comment: You can refer my blog, it will definitely help you -
https://medium.com/@bilochideeksha/asynchronous-validation-in-angular-reactive-forms-f25b1906c8aa